# How to replace the text in the buttons of my gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

I've added 9 buttons to my gridpane using the following:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        int number = 3 * r + c;
        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(number));
        gridPane.add(button, c, r);
    }
}
```

I want to replace the text in these buttons when they are clicked, but how do I do that? There's no identificator when adding these buttons, and when I try to print all the children of the gridpane it just gives me the memory address.

Comment: Do you want to replace the text of the button that was pressed or of the other buttons?

Comment: The pressed button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set and anonymous event like

```
for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        int number = 3 * r + c;
        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(number));
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                ((Button)e.getSource()).setText("Accepted");
            }
        });
        gridPane.add(button, c, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you can avoid accessing `Event.source`: `button` is effectively final, so you can just use `button` instead of `((Button)e.getSource())`. Using the `source` property is only useful, if you register the same event handler instance for multiple nodes or for some other reason cannot access the node it's registered for.

Comment: Yeah you are right. This seems to defeat the purpose of adding anonymous call for this instance.